# moodle Quiz notification email not working

Tags: email, moodle

I upgraded moodle 1.9 to 2.0 and 2.0 to 2.1 (as told before), now email notifications are not working, email is working as I tried to reset that password that I received in the email notification (so smtp server is connected properly). Now I have checked everywhere and enabled everywhere `mod/quiz:emailconfirmsubmission` and `mod/quiz:emailnotifysubmission allow`. I even checked in the database that everywhere permission is 1 for every role against above capabilities. I don't know what is wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure that the CRON jobs are running?

else login as admin, then visit the path on http://moodle_domain.dev/admin/cron.php

Emails are sent as cron jobs in Moodle.

Comment: thanks SmartMohi....you are right i didn't setup CRON job ,          now i set it up with CRONTAB in ubuntu to run it on interval of 30 min ....